# Multithreading on SLURM

Tags: linux, perl, parallel-processing, fork, slurm

I have a Perl script that forks using the [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) module.

To my knowledge, if I fork 32 child processes and ask the SLURM scheduler to run the job on 4 nodes, 8 processors per node, the code will execute each child process on every core.

Someone in my lab said that if I run a job on multiple nodes that the other nodes are not used, and I'm wasting time and money. Is this accurate?

If I use a script that forks am I limited to one node with SLURM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know `Parallel::ForkManager` doesn't make use of MPI, so if you're using `mpirun` I don't see how it's going to communicate across nodes. A simple test is to have each child output hostname.

One thing that commonly happens with non-MPI software launched with `mpirun` is that you duplicate all your effort across all nodes, so that they are all doing the exact same thing instead of sharing the work. If you use [`Parallel::MPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::MPI) it should work just fine.

Comment: I'm not certain how to proceed with such a test. How do I call the node that the forked job is running on.

Comment: If you have any good examples of `Parallel::MPI`(to save me time looking for one, PI is bringing out the whip) I would really appreciate it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: There are two tests:  1.  Is my job running on all four nodes?  Simply have each process output its hostname.  This can be something as simple as print `hostname`; (sorry I don't know how to escape backticks)  2.  Is my job duplicating all effort on all four nodes?  Look at your debugging output.  Let's say you are outputting the energy of a system for each timestep.  You'll see four indentical outputs of each timestep if your process is not sharing work across all four nodes.

Comment: @Mark Great answer. And you can escape backticks in comments with backslashes: the text `\`print \\`hostname\\`;\`` will produce `print \`hostname\`;`.

Comment: Interesting observation about the communication amongst the nodes. Using Parallel::ForkManager would be fine if you only want to use a single node, is this right?